# Using Github with VS 2010 and/or VS 2013 .Net Website

Tags: visual-studio, github

If you're familiar with a VS 2010 and VS 2013 default setup for a .NET website, you'll have two directories a `/projects/yourprojecthere` and `/websites/yourprojecthere`. To load the project/website in VS 2013 you need files from both. Does anyone know how to roll these two folders up into 1 repo for GitHub?

Comment: copy them into one folder and then push that to github? are you trying to use git instead of TFS in VS?

Comment: If i go that route, how do I coalesce local changes with the github repo?  We were using TFS. One of my guys wiped our TFS server so i'm starting over on source control.

Comment: source control (with git) a root directory that holds both the /websites and /project I would assume. I am sorry for your loss